# trigger pdf download in a query modal window

Tags: jquery, zend-framework2

I made a little application which at the end will generate a pdf file with DOMpdf.
But first the user have to fill out some forms in a Jquery Modal Window and after the validation i want to trigger the pdf file download and close the modal window.

My problem is that the pdf file instead of downloading, the modal window is opening it in its encoded text format.

How can i trigger the browser download in a Jquery modal window?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I'm new to Jquery this is what i have so far:

```
$('#PrintForm').submit(function(){
    if (is_xmlhttprequest == 0)
        return true;
    $.post(urlform, $('#PrintForm').serialize(), function(itemJson){
            var error = false;
            $( 'div' ).remove( '.alert' );
            //this is just some result of the validation
            if (itemJson.name != undefined){
                $('.element_name').append("<div class = 'alert alert-error'>"+itemJson.name[0]+"</div>");
                error = true;
            }

            if (!error){
               $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
            }

    }, 'json');

    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

if i do it with the ajax way i got a response something like this:

```
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
22 0 R
]
 ......... etc.
```

If i call in the browser the pdf generator url it starts to download the pdf file.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the modal window. It sounds more like that your server is sending the PDF with the wrong mime-type. You'll need to check your server-side code or the server configuration.

Comment: @RoToRa Thank you for your comment. I tested it, if i call the url only in the browser it start to download the generated pdf file. 'content-type', 'application/pdf'

Comment: Then you'l need to show some code. E.g. how do you trigger the download?

Comment: Were are you triggering the PDF download there? That just displays some data from a JSON document, that the URL returns.

Comment: @RoToRa yes first there is a form validation that is for the json. If the form valid it loads the pdf

Comment: @RoToRa I checked with Google Chrome's developer tool in the network panel if the form submitted and its valid it returns with a PDF file

Comment: You mean the post to `urlform` returns the pdf? How are you reading `itemJson.name[0]` then? Also you can't display a file returned by an AJAX call. You'll need to stop using AJAX and just supmit the form normally.

Comment: @RoToRa Thank you i had a misunderstanding of ajax usage it is working fine now

Comment: Maybe, but you still haven't shown where/how you are triggering the download.